# How to profile servlets in a remote tomcat deployment?

Tags: servlets, profiling

I'm looking for a tool to help me assess the performance of individuals methods in a servlet. I use Yourkit to profile local code. Is anyone aware of any profiling toolkit that can profile remote servlet instances?

I've looked at Apache Bench and JMeter, however I require more fine-grained information, ideally down to the code level (which Yourkit and JProbe can prove for local code).

Answer (score 0):

Forgive my ignorance, apparently Yourkit already supports the profiling of remote servlets.